# popen("ps -fu $USER" ,"r") doesn't give all original output result limited to 81 char long

Tags: c++, linux, popen, ps

im using linux redhat and in my code i have this simple fllow 
that supposed to read each line of the ps -fu $USER output 
it does read but not all of the line only half of it .

```
const char* szPs      = "ps -fu $USER";      // The PS command.
bool bSubProcessFound = false;
char szBuf[102400];  //big buffer
FILE* pPsOut = popen(szPs, "r");
  if (pPsOut == NULL) {

     bFailure = true;
     return (0);
  } 
// Go thru all commands.
  std::string sPsLine;

  bool bFound = false;
  int sizeofbug = sizeof(szBuf); //just checking size
  while (fgets(szBuf, sizeof(szBuf), pPsOut) != NULL) {

    LogWrite("befor   process: %s in ps", szBuf);
    // Erase new line at the end of ps string.
    szBuf[strlen(szBuf) - 1] = '\0';
    // Extract command line.
    sPsLine = szBuf;
    printf("after   process: %s in ps", sPsLine.c_str());
  }
```

and for example if i run the ps -fu $USER command in the shell im getting :

```
fooy    28407 28401  0 09:59 ?        00:00:04 java -Dappsubprocessname=catalina_gui -classpath .:/home/fooy/simple_java_server TCPServer
fooy    26256 26242  2 Oct20 pts/13   00:23:57 /usr/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,
```

but when i run the code im getting :

```
fooy    28407 28401  0 09:59 ?        00:00:03 java -Dappsubprocessname=catalin
fooy    26256 26242  1 Oct20 pts/13   00:23:20 /usr/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx512m
```

why does it cut the lines its looks like there is 81 chars limit ?
even simple command like this :

```
char* in = NULL;
  size_t len =0;
  FILE * psAux = popen("/bin/ps ax", "r");
  while(getline(&in,&sizeofbug,psAux)!=-1)
  {
      fputs(in,stdout);
  }
```

and the output is MAX 81 each line length:

```
3377 ?        Ss     0:00 httpd -f /home/wwwww02/DevDev/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
 3378 ?        S      0:00 httpd -f /home/wwwww02/DevDev/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
 3380 ?        S      0:00 httpd -f /home/wwwww02/DevDev/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
 3381 ?        S      0:00 httpd -f /home/wwwww02/DevDev/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
 3382 ?        S      0:00 httpd -f /home/wwwww02/DevDev/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
 3383 ?        S      0:00 httpd -f /home/wwwww02/DevDev/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
 3384 ?        S      0:00 httpd -f /home/wwwww02/DevDev/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
 3521 ?        S      0:15 [flush-8:32]
 3616 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: foo123 [priv]
 3624 ?        S      0:00 sshd: foo123@notty
 3625 ?        Ss     0:00 tcsh -c /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
 3639 ?        S      0:00 /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
 3640 ?        Ss     0:00 tcsh -c /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
 3655 ?        S      0:00 /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
 4150 ?        Sl     0:25 SSSBatchCCC.exe -name ValueTxImporter -ORBInitRef Nam
 4154 ?        S      0:29 [flush-8:48]
 4323 ?        S      0:00 httpd -f /home/wwwww02/DevDev/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
 4515 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: wwwww02 [priv]
 4526 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wwwww02@notty
 4527 ?        Ss     0:00 tcsh -c /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
 4547 ?        S      0:00 /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
 4657 ?        S      0:01 httpd -f /home/wwwww02/DevDev/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
 4742 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: foo123 [priv]
 4749 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: foo123 [priv]
 4754 ?        S      0:00 sshd: foo123@pts/7
 4756 ?        S      0:00 sshd: foo123@notty
 4757 ?        Ss     0:00 tcsh -c /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
 4773 ?        S      0:00 /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
 4782 pts/7    Ss     0:00 -tcsh
 5183 ?        Ss    46:18 /usr/sbin/abrtd
 5228 ?        Ss     2:24 abrt-dump-oops -d /var/spool/abrt -rwx /var/log/messa
 5337 pts/13   S+     0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/eclipse
 5338 pts/13   S+     0:00 /usr/lib64/eclipse/eclipse
 5352 pts/13   Sl+    6:37 /usr/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dorg.eclipse.equinox
 5472 ?        S      0:00 httpd -f /home/wwwww02/DevDev/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
 5519 ?        Sl    11:14 libvirtd --daemon
 5864 ?        S      0:01 httpd -f /home/wwwww02/DevDev/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
 6363 ?        S<     0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
```

Comment: What UID is executing the process?

Comment: C or C++? This is pretty different and in this moment you're mixing them...

Comment: @Adriano: The code shown obviously is C++.

Comment: Which value do you get for `sizeofbug `?

Comment: its c++ , and im getting 102400 in sizeofbug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `ps` itself which cuts the output.

From [`man ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html):

> If **ps** can not determine display width, as when output is redirected (piped) into a file or another command, the output width is
>                             undefined. (it may be 80, unlimited, determined by the TERM variable, and so on)

So if executing `ps` trough `popen()` one explicitly needs to tell `ps` how many "columns" it shall assume when printing output.

Again from [`man ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html):

> **OUTPUT MODIFIERS**
>      ...
>      **--cols** n        set screen width
>      **--columns** n     set screen width